# Google spreadsheet API with PHP - how to insert a row with data to beginning

Tags: php, google-sheets

I have this code which inserts a blank row near the top of a Google Sheet.

But how can I insert data in this row?

```
  $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);     
  $dr = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange();
  $dr->setSheetId(0);//first sheet/tab of spreadsheet file
  $dr->setDimension('ROWS');
  $dr->setStartIndex(1);
  $dr->setEndIndex(2);
  $ins = new Google_Service_Sheets_InsertDimensionRequest();
  $ins->setRange($dr);
  $ins->setInheritFromBefore(false);
  $ssr = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
  $ssr->setInsertDimension($ins);
  $busr = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  $busr->setRequests([$ssr]);
  $response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $busr, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with the following code:

```
$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
  'requests' => [
    'insertDimension' => [
      'range' => [
        'startIndex' => 1,
        'endIndex' => count($array)+1,
        'dimension' => 'ROWS',
        'sheetId' => 0
      ]
    ]
  ]
]);

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $request);
```